# What is the common file extension for LZFSE compressed files?

Tags: compression, zlib

What is the common file extension for LZFSE compressed files? Is it `.lz`? or `.lzfse`?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I had the same question. In my project I'm using the extension `.lzfse`.